# Gift free month of Apple Music notification

Tags: iphone, apple-music, family-sharing

I got this message and it took me to a website AppleMusic.co, but it was all in Spanish and said that something went wrong when I clicked on it.  What does this image mean?  Can I gift it to someone still?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case: all I had to do was wait a little bit.  I was able to gift the trial to someone through text message, and it worked perfectly, giving the person four months of Apple Music.

Comment: Should’ve given it to me :)